# Solving simultaneous recurrence relations.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Need help solving the following system:
$$s_n=s_{n-1}+2t_{n-1}+2$$
$$t_n=-2s_{n-1}+t_{n-1}+n$$ $$n\ge2$$
$$s_1=1$$ $$t_1=2$$

Comment: Just input $\ t_n$ into the equation for $\ s_n$

Comment: Write it as a matrix equation. $Q_n=M Q_{n-1} + K_n$

Comment: You can solve either by obtaining a recurrence purely in $s$ or purely in $t$ then once that is solved you can use one of your two recurrences to solve for the other. You can start by substituting from one equation into the other, you decide on the most appropriate choice.  Please post any of your attempts so that the mathSE community is in a better position to help you.

Comment: Z transforms will do the trick too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$s_n=s_{n-1}+2t_{n-1}+2\quad (1)\\
t_n=-2s_{n-1}+t_{n-1}+n\quad (2)$$

make $-2\cdot(2)+(1)$:

$$s_n-2t_n=5s_{n-1}+2(1-n)\to t_n=\frac{s_n-5s_{n-1}-2(1-n)}{2}$$

replacing at $(1)$:

$$s_n=s_{n-1}+2t_{n-1}+2\to s_n=s_{n-1}+s_{n-1}-5s_{n-2}-2(2-n)+2$$

$$s_n-2s_{n-1}+5s_{n-2}+2(1-n)=0$$

Can you finish?